# Creating New Sheet In Existing Excel Workbook Using Apache POI for Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to create a new sheet in an existing excel workbook using apache POI for java but have been unsuccessful so far. Can anyone please tell me how it is done?

Answer (score 7):

It's very easy. It's just like adding a new sheet to a new workbook, only you start with the existing workbook rather than a new one

```
 Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("/path/to/existing"));
 Sheet s = wb.createSheet();

 // Do something with the new sheet

 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/new/version");
 wb.write(out);
 out.close();
```

Comment: This is not working. it gives an error : Could not find 'internal references' EXTERNALBOOK

Comment: @TheGuest Make sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI, and make sure your file isn't corrupt!

Comment: 1. I am using the latest poi. 2. The file is not corrupt, I am CREATING a new Workbook instance (instead of loading an existing workbook) and trying to copy a sheet from a workbook which already exists on the disk. I guess this is a bug in Apache POI especially when creating HSSF workbook. I tried with XSSF, but I get a different error. I am trying to copy a sheet with macro from the existing workbook to a workbook that I am creating.

Answer (score 4):

```
//we can create any number of sheets for single workbook
HSSFSheet sheet1= workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
HSSFSheet sheet2= workBook.createSheet("sheet2");
HSSFSheet sheet3= workBook.createSheet("sheet3");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
HSSFSheet sheet1= workBook.createSheet("sheet1");
HSSFSheet sheet2= workBook.createSheet("sheet2");
HSSFSheet sheet3= workBook.createSheet("sheet3");
```