# About excel sheet manipulation using java

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel sheet with three columns name, age,address. Now I want to create another excelsheet in same work book with two columns name,count. That is I should find the number of counts of different names in first excel sheet and write into the second excel sheet. That is if in first excel sheeti the pinku occurs 5 times and name ram occurs 2 times . Then in the second sheet it should display each name and their counts. Can anyone suggest?

Comment: Pinku, where is your code? Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436243/creating-new-sheet-in-existing-excel-workbook-using-apache-poi-for-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436243/creating-new-sheet-in-existing-excel-workbook-using-apache-poi-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear. what's your problem exactly?
if your using Apache Poi,then you can get the workbook from an existing excel file like this:

```
inputStream = new FileInputStream(File yourFile);
workbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
```

then you can get the first sheet from workbook and iterate on it's rows and check first cell(name) of each row and count number of repetition for each name. after that you can create a new sheet like this:

```
newSheet = workbook.createSheet(newSheetName);
```

and fill it as you want.

Comment: Thank you so much .It was really useful. As I am new to this concepts I am confused how to compare first cell only and I want to take that cell content and its count.

Comment: Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    
    
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

Comment: I mean when we are using cellIterator it wil iterate all the columns in a row right. How can I limit that to only first column.