# how can i create a sheet in a created excel workbook?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
String tablaExcel = "Borrador-pantalla.xlsx";
        String rutaTablaExcel = "C:\\Users\\6001238\\Desktop\\"
                + tablaExcel;
        String hoja = "Hoja1";

        XSSFWorkbook libro = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet hoja1 = libro.createSheet(hoja);
```

I can not create a sheet in my created excel on java using apache poi
eclipse

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436243/creating-new-sheet-in-existing-excel-workbook-using-apache-poi-for-java. Look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this.

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\6001238\\Desktop\\yourFileName.xlsx"); 
Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("YourSheetName"); 
--- Rest of the code ---
```